# Layover at Heathrow

Tags: transit, lhr, moscow, aeroflot, aer-lingus

(English is not my first language. Apologies in advance for any grammar mistakes!)

I am flying to LHR from Dublin with Aer Lingus at 19:20 (Terminal 2) and have an Aeroflot flight leaving for Moscow at 22:45(Terminal 4).

They are on different tickets so I have to go through custom (I am from non-EU country) and recheck my bag.etc

Is 3h 25m enough for this?

I have another connecting flight with Aeroflot in Moscow so I have to take the flight to Moscow on time...

Should I change the flight with Aer Lingus?

Comment: Yes, you will have plenty of time to check in for a new flight, go through security and even have a dinner.

Comment: Your English is perfectly fine; my edits were just to add spaces between words.

Answer (score 2):

According to Heathrow's own connection planner, [the minimum connection time between these two flights is 90 minutes](http://www.heathrow.com/flight-connections/personal-connection-planner/EI178/SU2585/18-JUL-2017/18-JUL-2017/4/6A). Since you have 3h25m you'll have plenty of time (I ran the simulator with random dates, but the flights should be the correct ones):

[image: LHR connection tool]